# Renderizar componente de notificação na tela

Tags: javascript, react

Olá, estou tentando renderizar um componente de notificação na tela quando o botão de submit for clicado, porem estou retornando o componente direto no return, não está funcionando porque é o jeito errado, mas eu não sei como é o jeito certo de se fazer.

Basicamente eu tenho uma função de submit, nela eu passo uma outra função chamada `HandleError`, essa função retorna um componente  `Notification`que eu criei, ele esta funcionando perfeito pq eu testei em outro lugar, mas ao colocar ele no return nada acontece quando o botão de submit é clicado, gostaria de saber o porque. Obrigado desde ja.

Obs: Não estou retornando nada no htlm, apenas a função `HandleSubmit`ao clicar no botão.

```
const [input, setInput] = useState("");

async function handleSubmit(e) {
e.preventDefault();
const data = input;
try {
  const response = await service.create(data);
  handleError(response.status);
  return response;
} catch (err) {
  handleError(err.response.status);
  }
}

function handleError(statusCode) {
  if (statusCode === 201)
    return (
      <Notification
        title="Teste"
        description="teste do teste"
        type="success"
       />
     );
else
  return (
    <Notification title="Teste" description="teste do teste" type="error" />
  );
}
```

Codigo do meu componente de notificação

```
function Notification({ title, description, type }) {
 return (
   <div>
     {notification[type]({
       message: title,
       description: description,
     })}
   </div>
 );
```

}

Basicamente é essa notification que vai aparecer na tela caso o envio do formulario funcione e de tudo ok

[image: componente de notificaçao]

Comment: Por favor, coloque o código inteiro do seu componente. Do jeito que a questão está, não dá para saber exatamente o que está acontecendo ou ou que você quer que aconteça.

Comment: Olá, eu atualizei a questão e coloquei o código do componente e o retorno esperado dele, se não entender mais alguma coisa que avisa que eu tento explicar, fico no aguardo da ajuda Obrigado!

Comment: Pedro, como está o estilo do seu componente? Como ele deve aparecer na tela? Como um modal? Existem várias estratégias aí. Uma delas é controlar se este componente estará visivel ou não se ele já estiver na DOM ou até mesmo usando o Portal que é um conceito onde esse elemento é renderizado "fora" da DOM.